# Pass a value from a Tkinter entry to a variable by pressing "ENTER"

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to make my own terminal with Tkinter to have full controle of everything that happens in the terminal.
My problem is that I don't know how to listen for the user to press the ENTER key to send a command to the program so that the program can execute the entered command. I've searched the internet but I cannot find a solution to this.
So what I want is to send a stringvalue to a variable through an entry box, so that the program can process the variable, with just a single press on the ENTER key.
Is there an easy solution to this? This is my code so far:

```
#Needed modules in the future
import time, os, sys, logging
from pynput import *
from tkinter import *

#The variable that stores the input
userin = ''

#Creating window
root = Tk()
root.geometry('1080x660')
root.title('Terminal')
root.configure(bg="black")

#Making my entrybox
Entry(root, textvariable=userin, fg='lime', bg='black').grid()

#The regular mainloop :)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing three things: a saved reference to the `Entry` (or a `StringVar` for it, but that's not necessary in this case), a binding for the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key, and a function that does whatever you want to do with the contents of this widget.

Change this line, which makes an `Entry` widget but provides no way to refer to it:

```
Entry(root, textvariable=userin, fg='lime', bg='black').grid()
```

to this:

```
e = Entry(root, textvariable=userin, fg='lime', bg='black')
e.grid()
def process(event=None):
    content = e.get() # get the contents of the entry widget
    print(content) # for example
# bind enter key (called return in tkinter) to the entry widget and
# connect it to the process function
e.bind('<Return>', process)
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I'm new to the whole binding part and I'm not so sharp with Tkinter yet. This code is exactly what I need for my program, thanks a lot!